# Data time not present in photos transferred to PC from Lumix TZ11

Tags: camera, date-time

I have a Lumix TZ11 camera. My problem is: the photos transferred to PC from camera DO NOT contain the date/time stamp of the photos taken. However, when viewed in the camera, I can see the date/time stamp of those photos.
I'd highly appreciate if anyone can let me know how to transfer photos with original date/time stamp to PC.
Thanks in advance,
Don

Answer (score 0):

Try and external memory card reader.  Normally JPEG(and others) contain EXIF data block which has all of the information including date and time embedded.  What software are you using to examine the date and time for the pictures?  If you just using Windows Explorer and looking at the date and time stamps provided that could be the difference right there.  The camera can read the EXIF data and "windows explorer" can not.

If you have at least Windows XP you should be able to right click a single image and select Properties.  After that Click the details tab, and it *should* display the EXIF data.

Comment: I'm trying with both XP and Windows 7. In both versions, I'm not seen the date/time. In fact my problem is the date/time stamp appear "IN" the photos itself. I can see the date/time in photos when viewed from camera, but the same seem to be missing when transferred to PC and also printed. - Don

Comment: @Don Most software does not print the EXIF data or timestamp. I am also not sure what software does that.  If you got an external card read it might transfer the data and time correctly.  Otherwise you will have to use software to change the date and time to match the EXIF data. 
 http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Digital-Photo-Tools/Exif-Date-Changer.shtml

Comment: @Don Ignore the previous link. 
 http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/
Try that one a couple photo and see if that helps.